# Read a file with a single line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, file

I am using the below code to read a file word by word in bash

```
while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
    echo "word = '$word'"
    done
done  < My_File
```

However, the above code does not work since `My_File` has only a single line. How should I modify the code?

Comment: The code in your question should actually work, even though the outer loop is only iterating once... unless, perhaps, your one line isn't actually terminated by a newline (in which case `read` will return false, so the body of the loop won't run).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Reading Into An Array

This reads a single line into an array, splitting on characters in IFS (by default, spaces tabs and newlines).

```
read -r -a words <My_File || (( ${#words[@]} ))
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
  echo "Read word: $word"
done
```

The `||` condition prevents `set -e` (which you [shouldn't be using anyhow](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)) from causing the script to exit if there's no terminating newline.

---

#### Reading With A Space Delimiter

Note that this one works only if a regular space, and no other character, separates your words. If you want tabs instead, change `-d ' '` to `-d $'\t'`.

```
while IFS='' read -r -d ' ' word; word=${word%$'\n'}; [[ $word ]]; do
  echo "Read word: $word"
done <My_File
```

`word=${word%$'\n'}` strips any newline which may be present if your file wasn't in *exactly* the (space-delimiter-only) format given.

Comment: where should I give my file to the second code?   `done < My_file`?

Comment: @Admia, yes, exactly.

Comment: Note that the first solution exhibits the same problem as in the OP code, it will not process the last (or only) line when it is not terminated by a newline, which seems to be the issue.

Comment: @JavierVilla, try this yourself: `read -a line < <(printf '%s' "hello world")` -- it returns a nonzero exit status, but `declare -p line` shows that it contains both words.

Comment: @JavierVilla, ...the reason we don't unconditionally need `|| (( ${#line[@]} ))` or such in this case is that unless the user is using `set -e` or similar, there's nothing actually branching on the exit status of `read`.

Comment: @JavierVilla, ...that said, out of caution, I've amended to cover the `errexit` case.

Comment: For the second solution, what is the role of `[[ $word ]]`?

Comment: @Admia, because this is on the right-hand side of a `||`, that's run only if `read` reports that it failed. In that case, we check whether `word` is empty or not: If `read` reports that it failed, but it actually *did* write a word into the variable, then the presumptive cause is that there wasn't another space left in the file -- so we want to continue in to run the loop content anyhow.

Comment: The first `$word` in second solution is empty. Would you also advise me how can I resolve that? The solution by @RogueWave does not have this issue.

Comment: @Admia, does `declare -p word` show it as empty, or containing a nonprintable character (newline, carriage-return, tab, etc)?

Comment: @Admia, ...that's why the second answer explicitly says it's supposed to be used "only if a regular space, and no other character, separates your words". Perhaps I should have been explicit that it needs to be a *single* regular space -- if you have two spaces, then that'll be read as an empty word separating them. Likewise, if your file starts with an empty space, then your first word, before the separator, is an empty string.

Comment: @Admia, frankly, I think that's entirely defensible behavior. Think about if you have a CSV file `,foo,,bar` -- that means you have an empty field, then `foo`, then another empty field, then `bar`. This behaves exactly like that, but with spaces instead of commas.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When I open my file with `vim`, there is no space or tab at the beginning of file. So my file is like this: `word1 word2 word3`, and the words are separated by a space.

Comment: @Admia, if we replace `<My_File` with `< <(printf '%s' 'word1 word2 word3')`, then we know the *exact* contents of the string read as input, and there's no excess whitespace produced in output. Clearly, then, the actual file's content is not an exact match for the string `word1 word2 word3`.

Comment: @Admia, now, what I *expect* here is that you actually have a trailing newline, so if we read separated by spaces, your first word is `word1`, your second word is `word2`, your third word is `word3`, and your fourth word is a newline literal (`$'\n'`). This is part of why I said that the second approach is suitable if a single space is *the only delimiter*.

Comment: ...that said, I've patched it to accept the case where newlines are present, stripping any trailing newline from each word read before evaluating whether that word is empty.

Comment: @Admia, ...that said, why are you trying to use the second approach as opposed to the first one? If we exclude semantics you don't care about here such as the ability to parse empty fields, the only advantage the second one has is memory efficiency -- which might matter if your one-line file were megabytes or gigabytes long, but (1) it isn't, and (2) if you needed memory efficiency then the accepted answer would be unacceptable too.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so I use the first solution. Sorry for not following all the comments, I am new to bash and it is hard for me to understand the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust your code like this to account for lines without a terminating newline character:

```
(cat My_File; echo ) | while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
    echo "word = '$word'"
    done
done
```

This will add a newline at the end of the input, which won't change the output regardless of whether My_File has a newline or not.

-Rich Alloway (RogueWave)

Comment: That's a pretty significant amount of overhead (forking to set up the pipeline, forking to run `cat` as an external command), and has side effects on scoping (variable changes made in the loop disappear when the pipeline exits, as discussed in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)). I'd strongly suggest `while read line || [[ $line ]]` instead.

Comment: ...also, `for word in $line` is not just doing string-splitting but glob expansion: If the file contains `*`, then what will be echo'd is not `word = '*'` but a list of `word = 'filename'` results for every file in your current directory.